# What is the definition of Algebra (branch of mathematics)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure about posting this question and I don't know how it will be received. I hope you answer in comments so I can delete it if it turns out to be stupid.

Wikipedia defines Algebra as the study of mathematical symbols and the rules for manipulating them in formulas. But isn't all of mathematics then Algebra ? What is *not* Algebra ? What are the boarders between Algebra and analysis for example, or topology, analytic geometry or differential geometry.

If we take sets and topology then union, intersection and complements, closure, topological boarders, are operations that one can study and find their relations to each others. Is that Algebra ?

Or is Algebra the studying of general rules and properties of any operation sin any branch in Mathematics. Then it is not a branch of mathematics but a *certain step* or *investigation* in studying operations in mathematics and therefore *every branch in mathematics has its own Algebra!*.

Comment: I think probably no one knows. Some things definitely are algebra and other things definitely aren't, but there are probably a lot of things that you'd struggle to classify. I think the best you're going to do is that algebra is the study of abstract axiomatic systems like groups, rings, modules, etc. Not all axiomatic systems are algebra, but the ones I've listed above definitely are. The study of the additive and multiplicative properties of the real numbers is algebra, but for example the notion of a continuous function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is analysis

Comment: @SebastianMonnet Thanks, Could you mention some axiomatic systems that are not Algebra ? Topology, Set Theory ?

Comment: @Physor both not algebra. There are things in set theory that are sometimes called algebra. For example the operators $\cup$ and $\cap$ turn the power set of any set into a ring. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets

Answer (score 1):

"*What are the boarders between Algebra and analysis for example, or topology, analytic geometry or differential geometry*?"

The borders are fluid. A good example is the study of Lie groups and symmetric spaces in differential geometry and the induced study on the level of Lie algebras, vector spaces and algebras in general.
Here the borders overlap.

The differences become more apparent when we study basic objects in an area. For example, the basic objects in algebra are probably groups, rings and fields, including  Galois theory.
The primary objects of differential geometry are smooth manifolds.
These are hardly the same as the basic objects in algebra. The same applies for topology, analysis, number theory, algebraic geometry, PDE's and other areas.

Answer (score 1):

I started - some years ago - studying Algebra (Group Theory, Vector Spaces, Rings and Modules) and as a post-graduate was studying algebraic topology, algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory - algebra stopped being a subject and became the adjective "algebraic".

Algebra was contrasted, at the elementary stage, with Analysis - which was Real and Complex numbers and Calculus and Functions.

These are ways in to studying the properties of objects of mathematical interest. One of the major themes of 20th Century Mathematics was linking the perspectives from what had been different disciplines together (for example noticing that the fact that every complex polynomial in a single variable has a root - though it could be proved in many ways - was closely related to topological properties, which seen right make the result "obvious").

In some ways the classification still makes sense - Group Theory is still a subject with Algebra, but giving Algebra a useful definition which delineates clear disciplinary boundaries seems to me to be impossible. We can ask of any mathematical object "what symmetries does it possess?" and therefore attach a group to it. Sometimes that attachment can be done in a useful way which gives new insight - regardless of the discipline in which the object first came to attention.